# Composing type-level functions with implicit witnesses

Tags: scala, type-systems, implicits, path-dependent-type, type-level-computation

I am experimenting with some rather complex type-level calculations. There, I have some type tags (say, `A`, `B`, and `C`), and functions working on them, which are represented by implicit witnesses with path-dependent result types:

```
class A
class B
class C

trait F1[T] { type result }
trait F2[T] { type result }

implicit object f1OfA extends F1[A] { type result = B }
implicit object f2OfB extends F2[B] { type result = C }

trait Composed[T] { type result }
```

In the course of calculations, when "implementing" `Composed`, I need to make use of the fact that I can, given the above code, in principle transform `A` to `C` (in this example, I just need the composition, but actually there's more things involved).

However, I don't know how to express the composition, as I am always limited by the restriction that implicits are not transitively applied; the following code fails with "implicit not found":

```
implicit def composed1[X](implicit f2DotF1OfX: F2[F1[X]]): Composed[X] =  
  new Composed[X] { type result = f2DotF1OfX.result }

implicitly[Composed[C]]
```

What I actually tried to write initially was the following:

```
implicit def composed2[X](implicit f1OfX: F1[X], f2OfLast: F2[f1OfX.result]): Composed[X] =
  new Composed[X] { type result = f2OfLast.result }
```

This of course failed because there I used `f1OfLast` in the same parameter list it is defined. If it were not an implicit parameter, I could write

```
implicit def composed3a[X](f1OfX: F1[X])(f2OfLast: F2[f1OfX.result]): Composed[X] =
   new Composed[X] { type result = f2OfLast.result }
```

But it is not possible to do this using two *implicit* parameter lists, since they are disallowed by the language.

---

In short: how can I get a witness for `F2[F1[X]]` in the above examples? If necessary, I could also change the way of writing type-level functions, but I have not yet found another way to express them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use another type parameter and then require `f1OfX.result` to be that:

```
implicit def composed4[X, Y](implicit f1OfX: F1[X] { type result = Y },
  f2OfLast: F2[Y]): Composed[X] =
    new Composed[X] { type result = f2OfLast.result }
```

Comment: That's great! I hadn't thought of structural types.

Comment: @phg I'm not sure any of these terms are very well defined, but this is usually called a type refinement rather than a structural type.

Comment: @TravisBrown Yeah, you're right. The [spec calls](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#compound-types) a refinement "structural" if it does not overload anything.